# Why does Popper not work independently if I use bootstrap.bundle.js

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I understand that Bootstrap 4 needs Popper and if I use bootstrap.bundle.js, Bootstrap will work smoothly where it needs Popper for various functions. However, if I want to use Popper independently, I get a "Popper is not defined" error. Why is this?

The obvious workaround is to include popper.js first then bootstrap.js (without popper). If I include popper.js in my page, my popper works as expected. Obviously, I would rather be able to include only one file and get both libraries working separately and in combination.

Answer (score 0):

**Popper.js** is stated as required for Bootstrap 4, however, you can still use Bootstrap 4 JS without Popper, if you don't need tooltips, popovers, dropdowns, nor modals. Popper.js is not required if you use **bootstrap.bundle.js** or **bootstrap.bundle.min.js** instead of **bootstrap.js** or **bootstrap.min.js**.

**To answer your question:**
*That's because the bootstrap.bundle.* libraries contain popper internally but not independently*

> **Tip**: I cannot see a solid reason to try to use Popper independently when you can use it via Bootstrap unless you do not want to use Bootstrap altogether. You can also make use of some custom made functions to make the Popper.js accessible as if it was not part of Bootstrap ;)